# "Autoscroll to Source" missing in IntelliJ 2020.1.1

Tags: intellij-idea

where did my "target" icon go...I don't even see the options in the menu anymore...  Using version 2020.1.1

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006983339-Autoscroll-to-Source?page=1#community_comment_360001785219

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The button is removed when you have "Always Select Opened File" option enabled as this option does the same.